# Chapter comment with regulation

Tags: memoir

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}


\newenvironment{introduction}
{\centering%
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}%
%  \centering%
  \itshape\footnotesize\hspace{-1em}\ignorespaces%
}
{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{introduction}
Nunc condimentum, metus non ullamcorper fringilla, tellus tortor laoreet quam,
 eu pulvinar elit sem sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sodales auctor
 turpis, nec convallis nisi auctor quis. Nunc rhoncus auctor dolor, malesuada
 posuere diam vestibulum scelerisque.
\end{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sorry, i was still editing my question

Comment: This is a minor comment, but I am not sure if a picture and some LaTeX (only) is a good way to pose a question. For example, the system cannot analyse the text in your submission as it's a picture. Furthermore, I think that stating the question is a good exercise, which sometimes may help you solve your problem before you have to post it here.

Comment: Further to my comment, visually impaired members may not be able to determine what's in your post because either they cannot read it or they don't have software that can tell them what's in the picture. With a question with text it's different because (at least) some software can read it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\hangindent`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}


\newenvironment{introduction}
{\centering%
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}%
  \itshape\footnotesize\ignorespaces\hangindent1em%
}
{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{introduction}
Nunc condimentum, metus non ullamcorper fringilla, tellus tortor laoreet quam,
 eu pulvinar elit sem sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sodales auctor
 turpis, nec convallis nisi auctor quis. Nunc rhoncus auctor dolor, malesuada
 posuere diam vestibulum scelerisque.
\end{introduction}
Nunc condimentum, metus non ullamcorper fringilla, tellus tortor laoreet quam,
 eu pulvinar elit sem sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sodales auctor
 turpis, nec convallis nisi auctor quis. Nunc rhoncus auctor dolor, malesuada
 posuere diam vestibulum scelerisque.

\end{document}
```

[image]